# Reactive Mongo Extensions: Pass List Of Values In $in Query using `Query DSL`

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework-2.3, querydsl, reactivemongo

I am trying to pass multiples value in `$in` query using `Query DSL` with Reactive Mongo Extensions. But the result is empty list. Follwoing is my Code:

```
def findUsersByRolesIds(rolesIds: List[BSONObjectID], page: Int, pageSize: Int): Future[List[User]] = {
  logger.info("findUsersByRolesIds Reactive Repository Method");

  userGenericRepo.find($doc("userRoles._id" $in (rolesIds)), $doc("createdOn" -> -1 ), page, pageSize);
}
```

When i am trying to execute above code, the result was empty.

But when i pass, below code the result was return.

```
def findUsersByRolesIds(rolesIds: List[BSONObjectID], page: Int, pageSize: Int): Future[List[User]] = {
  logger.info("findUsersByRolesIds Reactive Repository Method");

  userGenericRepo.find($doc("userRoles._id" $in (BSONObjectID.apply("5548b098b964e7039852ff58"))), $doc("createdOn" -> -1 ), page, pageSize);
}
```

The main problem is that, i have multiple value, so that's why i create the list but here the list is not working. How this query is possible with `reactive mongo extenstions` and `Query DSL`.

Comment: Try `val query = $doc(...); println(s"query = ${BDONDocument pretty query}")` and then execute the query manually from the MongoDB CLI to check data are there.

Comment: @cchantep this is the output of query `query = {"userRoles._id":{"$in":[[{"$oid":"5548b098b964e7039852ff58"}]]}}`. still there is no data return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$in expects varargs, ie `val dsl: BSONDocument = "age" $in (1, 2, 3)`. So you cannot directly pass a collection to it. Try using this `"age" $in (rolesIds: _*)`.

Comment: thanks @fcs. This really help full for me. I think this is also need to include `Query DSL ` documentation.

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara do you mind sending a PR for that?

Comment: what is PR, i don't get it?